# Combined for loops

Tags: python, for-loop

In Python 3.x when we execute:

```
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        print (i,j)
```

We get:
0 0
0 1
1 0
1 1

Is there any way I can create 2 for loops where my range of i is (0,5) and range of j is (10,15)? Maybe like:

```
for i,j in range("myrange for i and myrange for j"):
print(i,j)
```

And the output would be:
0 10
1 11
2 12
3 13 and so on.

Comment: @miradulo The nominated duplicate is wrong, the OP needs `for i in range(3): j=i+10` and no nested loops at all. (This is probably still a duplicate of an existing question.)

Comment: @tripleee Oh...my mistake, didn't even consider that. Thanks.

Comment: Why 3 downvotes?

Comment: Probably because this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) -- you have one problem and seem to be asking about another which you think is related but isn't.

Comment: Maybe the way the asked was wrong which someone could have pointed out. Now I am unable to ask further questions. I don't know how I can reverse this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looping over pairs of related values, not over two independent lists. There is no nesting, just a single loop which fetches one pair at a time.

```
for i in range(5):
    j = i+10
    print(i, j)
```

In a more general case, if `j` is not always trivially derivable from `i`, you could say

```
for i, j in [(0, 10), (1, 42), (2, 12)]:
    print(i, j)
```

If `i` and `j` are populated from two existing lists of the same length

```
ilist = [0, 1, 2]
jlist = [10, 42, 12]
for i, j in zip(ilist, jlist):
    print(i, j)
```

If `i` is just the index within the `j` list, you can use `enumerate`:

```
for i, j in enumerate(range(10, 14)):
     print(i, j)
```

If you think  of nesting as dimensions, you can argue that there are rows (`i` values) and columns (`j` values to add);

```
for i in range(5):
    result = list()
    for j in (0, 10):
        result.append(i+j)
    print(*result)
```

So now, each `i` value gets added to each `j` value, and you collect and print those sums for each `i` value. Because the first `j` value on the first iteration of the inner loop is 0 every time, the first output value is conveniently identical to the input `i` value.